# Replacing images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with my project. I added a feature that when clicking on something will replace the image with a town. This does happen... but only for the one and two original pictures i just want one to be changed at a time.
this is the snippet URL [JS fiddle][1]

```js
var cDunes = document.getElementById('cDunes');
var eDunes = document.getElementById('eDunes');
var forest = document.getElementById('forest');
var oasis = document.getElementById('oasis');

cDunes.addEventListener("click", replaceCDune);
eDunes.addEventListener("click", replaceEDune);

function replaceCDune() {
  cDunes.src = "https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf";
}

function replaceEDune() {
  eDunes.src = "https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf"
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111096/download?f=9k7y8m7if6dkcq345y53s4yp4");
}
img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<img id="cDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy" />
<img id="eDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf" />
<img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy" />
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi" />
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi">
<img id="eDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf">
<img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy">
<img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy">
<img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy">
<img id="eDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf">
<img id="eDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf">
<img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy">
<img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy">
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi">
<img id="cDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy">
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi">
<img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy">
<img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy">
<img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy">
<img id="cDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy">
<img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy">
<img id="cDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy">
<img id="cDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy">
<img id="cDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy">
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi">
<img id="cDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy">
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi">
<img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy">
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi">
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi">
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi">
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi">
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi">
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi">
<img id="eDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf">
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi">
<img id="cDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy">
<img id="cDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy">
<img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy">
<img id="eDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf">
<img id="cDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy">
<img id="eDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf">
<img id="eDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf">
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi">
<img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy">
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi">
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi">
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi">
<img id="cDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy">
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi">
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi">
<img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy">
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi">
<img id="eDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf">
<img id="eDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf">
<img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy">
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi">
<img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy">
<img id="eDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf">
<img id="cDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy">
<img id="eDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf">
<img id="eDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf">
<img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy">
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi">
<img id="eDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf">
<img id="eDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf">
<img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy">
<img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy">
<img id="cDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy">
<img id="cDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy">
<img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy">
<img id="eDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf">
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi">
<img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi">
<img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy">
<img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy">
<img id="cDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy">
<img id="cDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy">
```

Comment: A man is reusing id. id should be unique. So if I comprehend correctly, I click on number one and it changes, I click on number two and it changes - yet number one should change back to original?

Comment: Please explain in a bit more detail as it is quite difficult to understand your overall goal here. Thanks!

Comment: I just want them all change one at a time each time you click on them

Comment: So a man wants them to change back on second click?

Comment: But if you could show me how to get the image to change back after another image has been clicked on that would be a lot of help!

Comment: yes, and get all the images to do the same as well

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood it correctly, merely one image should be changed/turned at a time.
This is more easily achievable if you change the structure a bit and store the original as the hover source in data-attributes.

Here is a cropped example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.onload = function(){
                //Assign event for each image holding a hover-src
                for(var tL=document.querySelectorAll('img[data-hover-src]'), i=0, j=tL.length; i<j; i++){
                    tL[i].addEventListener('click', replaceImage)
                }
            }

            function resetToOriginal(){
                //Sets all images holding a original-src back to it
                for(var tL=document.querySelectorAll('img[data-original-src]'), i=0, j=tL.length; i<j; i++){
                    var tS = tL[i].getAttribute('data-original-src');
                    (tS !== tL[i].src) && (tL[i].src = tS)
                }
            }

            function replaceImage(e){
                //Clicked element
                var tE = e.srcElement || e.target;

                //Storing the original src in a data-original-src-attribute if missing
                !tE.getAttribute('data-original-src') && tE.setAttribute('data-original-src', tE.src);

                //Reseting all the images
                resetToOriginal()

                //Change the src to the src in the data-hover-src-attribute
                tE.src = tE.getAttribute('data-hover-src') || tE.src
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img id="eDunes" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf" data-hover-src = 'https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf' />
        <img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy" data-hover-src = 'https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf'/>
        <img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi" data-hover-src = 'https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf'/>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9vv8m67n/

### Update

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            //Storing the images in an object array instead
            //The hover part is optional and if unset the tD in the createImages() function is used [1]
            var mImages = [
                {
                    src: 'https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf',
                    hover: 'https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf'
                },
                {src: 'https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy'},
                {src: 'https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi'}
            ];

            window.onload = function(){
                createImages(mImages) //Creating images and assiging events
            }

            //Creating images out of object
            function createImages(o){
                var tD = 'http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png'; //[1]: Default hover-src on undefined

                var tF = document.createDocumentFragment()
                for(var i=0, j=o.length; i<j; i++){
                    var tI = tF.appendChild(document.createElement('img')); //Creating a new HTMLImage
                    tI.src = o[i].src;
                    tI.setAttribute('data-hover-src', o[i].hover || tD);
                    tI.addEventListener('click', replaceImage)
                }
                document.body.appendChild(tF) //Appending images to the dom - here body
            };

            function resetToOriginal(){
                //Sets all images holding a original-src back to it
                for(var tL=document.querySelectorAll('img[data-original-src]'), i=0, j=tL.length; i<j; i++){
                    var tS = tL[i].getAttribute('data-original-src');
                    (tS !== tL[i].src) && (tL[i].src = tS)
                }
            };

            function replaceImage(e){
                //Clicked element
                var tE = e.srcElement || e.target;

                //Storing the original src
                !tE.getAttribute('data-original-src') && tE.setAttribute('data-original-src', tE.src);

                //Reseting all the images
                resetToOriginal();

                //Change the src
                tE.src = tE.getAttribute('data-hover-src') || tE.src
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- AJAX -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i have more than 50 images. Do you know a fast way to give them all that attribute?

Comment: @Liam Sperry: Maybe the updated solution suits a man better. Could be stored in another js file and just be included. Else a man has to work with css classes and the background-image.

Comment: @Liam Sperry: Is the hover image always or mostly the same?